# Actuator linking alternatives

Tags: parallel, series, controller, actuator

I am working on a project that requires raising and lowering a static flexible rubber to a max height of 300mm from a zero, flat point.

My issue, other than the fact my expertise lies within other areas of this project, is that I know very little about engineering (sorry).

I wanted to understand if it is possible to have a very large number of actuators or an alternative to an actuator that can lift the flexible surface, by working together to create any tilted, curved shape our computer program will create.

My limited knowledge in this area, tells me it may not be possible, due to voltage dropping, the power needed to lift every actuator simultaneously, but I want to find a solution.
If anyone can help, I am told this is the place to find it.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Voltage dropping is a problem you get to after selecting actuators, when you want to decide how to connect them all. We cant decide what solution needs too much power before knowing how much power we have to work with. A 1 kW actuator is just fine for a lab, but would not work with 4 AA batteries. How many actuators you actually need to get a specific shape for the rubber is a mechanical problem which we cant help with here

Comment: In fact, it is your computer program that should help you decide how many actuators you need. If you feed it enough data about the rubber, and the actuator you want to use, it should be able to know what shapes are and arent possible. Based one that, and based on what shapes you do need, you select the numbber of actuators. After that, you see how much current and power they each need and then check if you can supply that much.

Comment: John - Welcome and thanks for reading the [tour] already. My interpretation of your question is that you need to start with mechanical design, which is outside the scope of *this* part of Stack Exchange, but may be suitable for [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). I recommend that you check [their tour](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and [their help pages](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help) to check that your question is suitable. You can delete the question here, while it has no answers, if you agree that it's currently a mechanics question.

Comment: *any tilted, curved shape our computer program will create* <-- you need to define that. People making answers won't know what that is.

Comment: This is an engineering question, so should go there. However, consider that your rubber mat does a cubic spline interpolation (under certain ideal circumstances) between the positions of the actuators. I have met people who have made these systems, and the trick seems to be to get a commercial supply of cheap but adequate actuators, for instance ventilation flap drivers intended for automobiles. Choose actuator types that retain their position when powered off.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter of 300 mm is tricky, as there are lots of shapes which will be very difficult for the skin to adapt to.

**You really need to think about the mechanical properties first.**  As such, you may well find this is more suitable for Engineering SE.

A project with very similar parameters is the 1999 **Hyposurface project of Marc Goulthorpe**, now of MIT, which uses pneumatic actuators with a displacement of about 500 mm.  It's an extraordinary thing to watch, as it's also very fast.

[Blog post about Hyposurface](https://semanurcan.wordpress.com/2021/01/08/hyposurface-by-mark-goulthorpe/)
[image]

Another 3d surface system of quite a different kind is the "Kinetic Ball Sculpture" by ART+COM at the BMW museum, which uses balls on strings.
[Wired article](https://www.wired.com/2008/07/kinetic-structu/)
Endless videos, search results from Google:
[image]